# chrome.declarativeNetRequest is undefined

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to dynamic filter using chrome.declarativeNetRequest.updateDynamicRules.
The chrome extension throws error that chrome.declarativeNetRequest is undefined.

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'updateDynamicRules' of undefined

The chrome version is 91.0.4472.114
Other callbacks like chrome.runtime.onMessage work perfectly

Any suggestion will be really helpful.

Comment: Without seeing [MCVE](/help/mcve) we have to guess. You either forgot to add declarativeNetRequest to permissions in manifest.json or you're trying to use it in the content script which is not possible or you didn't reload the extension on chrome://extensions page after editing.

Answer (score 1):

Adding "declarativeNetRequest" to "permissions" in manifest.json worked for me.

```
{
    "permissions": [
        "activeTab",
        "tabs",
        "declarativeNetRequest"
     ],
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks wOxxOm I was trying to add declarativeNetRequest from content script. Moving it to service worker solved the issue.